# Decomposition of a group whose Cayley graph is a tree

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

This is an exercise taken from Chapter 9 of a French book, *Géométrie et Théorie des Groupes*. It says, roughly, the following:

Show that a finitely generated hyperbolic group, whose Cayley graph is a tree, is isomorphic to an amalgamated sum of certain number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Have I missed something here, but isn't the Cayley graph of $G=$PSL$_2(\mathbb{Z})$ a tree, but $G$ is a free product of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? Is it possible to rewrite this free product in another way so that the statement of the exercise holds? All I know is that it contains a subgroup isomorphic to the free group of rank two.

Comment: I am probably missing something silly here, but how can a group with an element of order $3$ have a tree for its Cayley graph? Surely the element of order $3$ gives a loop of order $3$ in the graph?

Comment: @user1729: presumably you don't use the element of order $3$ as one of the generators.

Comment: @Qiaochu yes, true, but it still corresponds to a loop. If $w$ is an element of order three then it gives a loop in the Cayley graph. (As does any relator). Or, to put it another way, the presentation complex contains $2$-cells so the universal cover (the Cayley complex) cannot have a tree as its 1-skeleton. However, its 1-skeleton is the Cayley graph.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant quasi-isometric to a tree?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Whatever generators you use, there's some word in them which has order $3$...

Comment: @user1729: I verified in the mentionned book, the question is correctly formulated.

Comment: @Seirios Then there is something odd going on with, I suspect, a definition or a translation of a definition. A group $G$ has a tree for its Cayley graph only if $G$ is free (or, for people wanting to confuse people, you could make the Cayley graph of $F_n\ast C_2$ into a tree by writing the $C_2$ generator as an undirected edge). This is because a group acts freely on its Cayley graph, and if a group acts freely on a tree then it is a free group. Or use the covering space argument, above.

Comment: I think the exercise is correct. But I think I may have confused myself with another fact. The exercise is saying that if the Cayley graph is a tree, then it has this decomposition. But there are some groups with this decomposition whose Cayley graphs are not trees. Take, for example, the infinite dihedral group, which you can write as a free product of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$ Anyway, I think I was confused because PSL$_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts freely on a tree, but that tree is not its Cayley graph. Hatcher has a picture of the 1-skeleton in his algebraic topology book, in which there are loops.

Comment: @Hanna Whereabout in Hatcher? Also, $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on a tree (as does any free product - this is the Bass-Serre tree), but the action is not free. It is free on the edges thought (but every torsion element fixes some vertex).

Comment: Page 78, right after example 1.48. And yes, you're right, the action isn't free--my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3$ can be written as an amalgamated sum $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}$, where the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is zero and the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by $3$.

Comment: Thanks, I was having a blank moment.